# Can EVM Istambul release run contracts compiled with solidity up to v0.8.4?

Tags: solidity, evm, istanbul

Reading from the [Solidity release notes](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/Changelog.md), for release 0.5.14 I read "*Set the default EVM version to Istanbul*". While for 0.8.5 I read: "*Set the default EVM version to Berlin*".

Does this mean that EVM before Istanbul could run contracts written in Solidity up to 0.5.13, while Istanbul supports contracts written in Solidity up to 0.8.4?